# How to fetch Image::Info object for an existing image

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

If I have an existing image, how can get a reference to its Image::Info object? In particular, I want to read an option (that was previously set using image.define(...)) from it using the [] operator.

If there is any other way to read a value set via image.define(...) from an image, that would be perfect as well.

Answer (score 0):

The define method is the same as []=, so [you can get the option value using []](https://rmagick.github.io/info.html#aref).